# swift UINavigationController delegate

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have an `UINavigationController` with a a `UIBarButtonItem` on the left side. This navigation controller is a subclass of a UIViewController.
I wrote a delegate method, which is called, when I push that bar button. 
But on parent ViewController this delegate doesn't get called, I don't know why. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Here are some code....

this is the navigation controller

```
protocol CollectionControllerDelegate {
    func onMenu()
}

class CollectionController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: CollectionControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func onMenu() {
        self.delegate?.onMenu()
    }
}
```

And this is the parent view controller class, the mainController is the navigation controller, which I described above.

```
(self.mainController!.viewControllers[0] as! CollectionController).delegate = self
```

And this function doesn't get called, I don't understand :(

```
func onMenu() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `var delegate: CollectionControllerDelegate?` is nil. If that is the case you are setting a wrong delegate here:

```
(self.mainController!.viewControllers[0] as! CollectionController).delegate = self
```

It the first view controller depends on at what point in code do you call it. It is always a top view controller on UINavigationController stack, buy you have to make sure it was pushed already.

Also make sure your `@IBAction` is connected and is getting called.

Comment: I checked it, it is not nil on the view controller side, this is why I don't understand.

Comment: And what happens if you call it manually from the debugger? Does something happen? If not, it's not connected well, if yes, your IBAction is not set up well.

Comment: The IBAction is get called, when a I push the button, but delegate doesn't get called on the view controller side

Comment: Could you add more context code around this line? `(self.mainController!.viewControllers[0] as! CollectionController).delegate = self` Like how you implement the protocol and where you set it

Comment: In the ViewDidLoad. The implementation code is above.

Comment: Which view Controller implement this protocoll ?

Comment: But I don't understand why. I set the delegate here: (self.mainController!.viewControllers[0] as! CollectionController).delegate = self

Comment: The parent view controller of the navigation controller implements this protocol.

Comment: That might be a different CollectionController from the one that you're interacting with. In that case you might be setting a delegate to self, but to another controller

Comment: Try doing something like changing a background color of `(self.mainController!.viewControllers[0] as! CollectionController)` to make sure you have the correct view controller that you're setting your delegate to.

Comment: You are right, that is another CollectionController. Do you have any idea why there are more than 1 CollectionController?

Comment: It depends on your whole code implementation. I really can't know just from this. I suggest you poke around and see which viewController is the one being displayed. After that it should all work as expected.

Comment: I found the problem, but after a I fix id.         (self.mainController!.viewControllers[0] as! CollectionController).delegate = self caused that nothing displayed, just blackness. Can somebody help me?